# use width inside of calc

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something like this:

```
.my-style {
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - calc(width / 2));
}
```

Later I am changing the width to 90px and I want the margin grow accordingly.
It doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: You should use an CSS alternative or Javascript (jQuery).

Comment: Try using SASS or LESS.

Comment: @Ennui: SASS / LESS / STYLUS / ... don't change the css in runtime!

Comment: Use JS then.  calc() has pretty bad browser support so it's not tremendously reliable (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Safer to use JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newest browser's SHOULD support it, I tried the following code.

*This is a webkit example I made, so check it in chrome*

**CSS**

```
p {      
      -webkit-var-a: -webkit-calc(1px + 3px);
      margin-left:-webkit-calc(-webkit-var(a) + 5px);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>This text should have margin-left, but it doesn't</p>
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/uqE8b/

If you inspect the `<p>` element you can see that it DOES see the code as valid, it just doesn't do anything... So it seems that for now you have to use javascript, LESS or anything equivelent as it's still a experimental feature.

**EDIT:**

it **DOES** seem to work when you make the var a plain number:

```
p {      
      -webkit-var-a: 3px;
      margin-left:-webkit-calc(-webkit-var(a) + 5px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uqE8b/1/

***So to answer your question, yes this is possible, but I would not recommend it for now.***

**CSS**

```
.my-style {
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    -webkit-var-width: 50px;
    margin-left: -webkit-calc(50% - -webkit-var(width) / 2);
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ShsmX/

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can't do something like that with standard CSS, you should investigate an alternative such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)</s>

Edit: I was wrong, CSS3 supports this if you use var() within calc():

```
.my-style {
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: calc(50% - (var(width) / 2));
}
```

I think should do it.

Comment: you should also declare the var, f.e. var-width: 100px;

Comment: I can't get it to work either, I pulled it from some tutorials, it's possible my browser doesn't support it. In which case, try using LESS or similar.

Comment: LESS doesn't change the css in runtime. Only in "compilation" time.

Comment: LESS is dynamic CSS, and does not compile. You may be thinking of SASS

Comment: Both less and sass can be compilated and dynamically interpreted in browser

Answer (score -2):

```
.my-style {
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: calc(100% - calc(width / 2));
}
```

Try like this, it worked wonder for me.